# Send email with Follow up flag and reminder datetime in Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib, mimemultipart

I am trying to send email using Python script and MIMEMultipart object.

The sending of email is working just fine, but I am trying to flag the email Follow Up with a bell **Reminder time**. Currently [Reply-By] is not creating a reminder for recipient.

This action would be the same as when user add follow up flag and **check the reminder** at Outlook and there will be a **alarm bell icon** when recipient view the email.

My current code:

```
#Email settings for Sender(From), Recipient (To), CC, Subject and High Priority level
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = ", ".join(email_recipients)
msg['Cc'] = ", ".join(cc_recipients)
msg['Subject'] = '''UPDATE OF PAYMENT SCHEDULE FOR ''' + next_month_name.upper() + ''' ''' + next_month_year
msg['X-Priority'] = '2'
msg['X-Message-Flag'] = 'Follow up'
msg['Reply-By'] = '16/06/2022 09:00:00'

msg.attach(MIMEText(email_body, 'html'))

#Code to send email
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(email_user, email_pass) 
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: These are undocumented Microsoft "extensions", I don't think there is a way to make sure they work even across different versions of Outlook.

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)